# CLLocationmanager updateLocations delegate method not getting called in iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit

Am using CLLocationManager to get current location . Specifically in iOS 8 , it's delegate methods are not getting fired .

I have set allow in location services please refer screen shot below
[image]

Please find my code below:

`self.myLocationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
    [self.myLocationManager setDelegate:self];
    self.myLocationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    self.myLocationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    [self.myLocationManager startUpdatingLocation];`

and i tried using method of iOS 8 . And set a property `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` in plist but still am not able to get location

`self.myLocationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];`

Comment: you must add this line: [self.myLocationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];   before  [self.myLocationManager startUpdatingLocation];

Comment: myLocationManager must be a strong property, also...

Answer (score 1):

Step 1:

Add the below code:

```
SEL requestSelector = NSSelectorFromString(@"requestAlwaysAuthorization");
if ([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined &&
    [locationManager respondsToSelector:requestSelector]) {
    [locationManager performSelector:requestSelector withObject:NULL];
} else {
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

Step 2:

Add `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` to info.plist

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you've set a value for `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription`.

Comment: i added the value . Still it not firing